# Why get "Permission Needed" everytime for my word plugin?

Tags: plugins, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I am builing Word Plugin, I follow the tutorial to set up SSO by adding

```
<WebApplicationInfo>
      <Id>{application GUID here}</Id>
      <Resource>api://localhost:44355/{application_GUID here}</Resource>
      <Scopes>
        <Scope>openid</Scope>
        <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
        <Scope>profile</Scope>
        <Scope>files.read.all</Scope>
      </Scopes>
</WebApplicationInfo>
```

into my manifest file, however, everytime I **refresh** the page, when I click my plugin icon, it pops **"Permission Needed"** dialog box to ask above permissions, even I already gave the consent before, I thought it will remember my consent for the app. It shouldn't bother me again and again, this behavior happens before **"Office.initialize"** event, therefore not my code cause that.

My question, any way to let the "permission needed" only popup at first time, and after I gave the consent no matter how many times I refresh the page, when I click my plugin icon, it will not popup again?

Thanks

*** More info appended ***

I use my "Work or School" account login to office365, the URL is https://word.office.com

choose any word file, and click my plugin.

[image]

Then give the consent for app.

[image]

Then, If I reload the current Word page (by pressing Ctrl+F5) and click my plugin icon again, it repeat the above steps which I already give the consent.

That not make sense, or it only happens when I am developing, then it will be ok when published to Microsoft AppSource?

Comment: You'll have a better chance of getting responses if you tag your questins corectly. Take a look at how I've tagged this one (and some others, recently).

Comment: Are you testing with desktop Office or Office Online? Are you using a Microsoft Account to test with or a Work or School (Office 365) account? Also, could you clarify what you mean by "refresh the page"? Do you mean refresh the task pane?